# EL map lookup using string key containing single quote

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, el

I have a Java `HashMap<String,String>` that is being provided to a JSP page (`itemTypesByKey`) via a `ModelAndView` from Spring, and a separate structure containing a list of keys. (These keys may or may not result in a valid lookup.) I enumerate over these keys, and snag values from the map.

```
Map<String, String> itemTypes = new HashMap<>();
itemTypes.put("NormalValue", "INGREDIENT");
itemTypes.put("Apostro'Value", "INGREDIENT");
ModelAndView mav = ...
mav.addObject("itemTypesByKey", itemTypes);
```

*The problem* I'm seeing, is that if my key contains an apostrophe, the lookup fails.

My code (for debugging purposes):

```
Key Name: ${currentKeyName}
Not Empty: ${not empty itemTypesByKey[currentKeyName]}
Type: ${itemTypesByKey[currentKeyName]}
All Suite Types: ${itemTypesByKey}
```

Ends up printing, for two separate keys:

```
Key Name: NormalValue
Not Empty: true
Type: INGREDIENT
All Suite Types: {NormalValue=INGREDIENT, Apostro'Value=INGREDIENT}

Key Name: Apostro'Value
Not Empty: false
Type:
All Suite Types: {NormalValue=INGREDIENT, Apostro'Value=INGREDIENT}
```

I understand escaping apostrophe *literals* when they're used to lookup a value, but why does this fail if my key *contains* an apostrophe? How can I safely perform a lookup in my map regardless of whether the value of my key contains special characters?

**Edit:** I'm using Spring version 3.1.4 (mvc, expression, etc.), and this issue does not affect keys containing exclamation points, or other special characters I could think to test.

Comment: Because the apostroph will converted into thier code (&#39;). The same issue with the quotation sign =( .

Comment: Shouldn't the lookup happen internally prior to anything being printed to the page?

Comment: actually yes. But 'actually' is actually not a word.^^

Comment: Please don't mix [JSTL](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) with [EL](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info). I fixed the tagging.

Comment: Thanks @BalusC - we're using both, but you're right that this snippet only deals with EL.

Comment: As far as I've read in http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/  Strings (which are what your `itemTypes` Map uses) are delimited by single quotes.  They state, "To put a single quote itself in a string use two single quote characters."  Your key is a String which I believe still operates under this constraint.  I'm curious if other special characters (exclamation, double quote, etc...) cause you the same issue?

Comment: @CraigOtis - Does my answer address your questions?  If not, would you relay how it doesn't?

Comment: @ZackMacomber Sorry for the delay, have been traveling the past few days. Trying your suggestion now.

Comment: @ZackMacomber To answer your other question, other special characters do not cause this issue, An exclamation point works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below are some tests alongside results. In order to use an apostrophe inside of a key you have to use two single quotes. On top of that, a key that has a single quote in it or special characters (exclamation, double quotes, etc...) needs to have single quotes surrounding it. Bottom line is surround your keys with single quotes & use two single quotes if you have a single quote in your key.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
    Map<String,String> itemTypes = (Map) parser.parseExpression("{NormalValue:'INGREDIENT',ApostroValue:'INGREDIENT'}").getValue();
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : itemTypes.entrySet())
        System.out.println(e.getKey() + ": " + e.getValue());
}
```

Prints keys & values fine

```
parseExpression("{NormalValue:'INGREDIENT',Apostro'Value:'INGREDIENT'}")
```

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1046E:(pos 51): Cannot find terminating  for string

```
parseExpression("{NormalValue:'INGREDIENT',Apostro''Value:'INGREDIENT'}")
```

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1043E:(pos 33): Unexpected token. Expected 'colon(:)' but was 'literal_string'

```
parseExpression("{NormalValue:'INGREDIENT','Apostro''Value':'INGREDIENT'}")
```

Prints fine

```
parseExpression("{NormalValue:'INGREDIENT',Apostro\"Value:'INGREDIENT'}")
```

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1045E:(pos 33): Cannot find terminating " for string

```
parseExpression("{NormalValue:'INGREDIENT','Apostro\"Value':'INGREDIENT'}")
```

Prints fine

```
parseExpression("{NormalValue:'INGREDIENT',Apostro!Value:'INGREDIENT'}")
```

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1043E:(pos 33): Unexpected token. Expected 'colon(:)' but was 'not(!)'

```
parseExpression("{NormalValue:'INGREDIENT','Apostro!Value':'INGREDIENT'}")
```

Prints fine

Comment: I appreciate your answer Zack, but I'm seeing different behavior on my machine. (Using Spring Expression 3.1.4.) https://gist.github.com/craigotis/6f3cfaf29ecde4b0c63a

Comment: @CraigOtis Weird...when I copy your gist down and run it all of them are passing for me

Comment: It's likely related to the Spring Expression version then - which are you using?

Comment: @CraigOtis I'm using spring-expression-4.1.4...maybe that's the difference

Comment: Almost definitely. I should have mentioned the version in the original answer - I just updated it.

Comment: I found this: http://www.springframework.net/BreakingChanges-1.1.txt which mentions that only single quotes are escape characters, but I can't tell specifically which product/library that's for.